# how to pass a select value into a php var without refreshing the page

Tags: php, ajax, html

I want `$con` to be the selected value which is happening cause this `echo '<p class="pop"></p>';` is working but I don't know how to put `$con` inside my query so it can give me the selected value there.

This is the error in the php script

> **Notice**: Undefined index: evento in **C:\xampp\htdocs\simulator\modulo1\error.php** on line **2**
>   **Notice**: Undefined index: evento in **C:\xampp\htdocs\simulator\modulo1\error.php** on line **201** Conferencia

but how it is possible if is printing the value conferencia that is coming from error.php? I don't get it

```html
index.php

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tipologias').change(function () {
                var con = $('#tipologias').val();
                console.log(con);

                $.ajax({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "error.php",
                    data: {evento:con}
                })
                .done(function(data){
                    $(".pop").html(data);
                });                
            });
        });
    </script>

<?php
    require_once 'error.php';    
    $con= $_POST['evento'];
    echo $con;
    echo '<p class="pop"></p>'; /* this work and print selected value without refreshing the page*/
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT requerimientos FROM tipologia where               tipologia=$con");
    $rows = $query->fetch_array(); 
?>
```

Comment: only via [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming